# How variable scopes work in higher order functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, scope, settimeout, debouncing, javascript-scope

I will use a `debounce` function as example.

```
const debounce = (func, wait) => {
  let timeout;

  return function executedFunction(...args) {
    const later = () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      func(...args);
    };

    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
  };
};
```

then I create a dummy function:

```
const dummy = () => console.log('debounced');
```

then I create a debouncedDummy function:

```
const debouncedDummy = debounce(dummy, 1000);
```

and then I call `debouncedDummy` multiple times:

```
debouncedDummy();
debouncedDummy();
debouncedDummy();
debouncedDummy();
```

What I need help understanding is why `timeout` variable is shared across multiple calls of `debouncedDummy` ?
What if `timeout` was defined outside the scope of `debounce` ?
What if `timeout` was defined inside the scope of `executedFunction` ?

Comment: "*What if timeout was defined outside the scope of debounce ?*" in this case, nothing happens. However, if you debounce two different functions, they'll share the same `timeout`, so `debouncedA(); debouncedB();` would not run twice. "*What if timeout was defined inside the scope of executedFunction ?*" then effectively the function is not debounced. Each time you call `debouncedDummy()` a new `timeout` is created, so `debouncedDummy(); debouncedDummy();` does not interfere with each other, therefore both execute.

Comment: [Outside `debounce`](https://jsbin.com/fuborug/1/edit?js,console) and [inside `executedFunction`](https://jsbin.com/paqocik/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: @VLAZ Actually the second case, I just found out that falls into "stale closure" category, or rather the inverse of it